# XSD With XML have attribute in elements

Tags: xml, postgresql, xsd

I need convert XML to XSD Mappings use for Excel 2016. This XML were exported from Postgres v8.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>
    <header>
        <column name="code" type="bpchar" />
        <column name="type" type="bpchar" />
    </header>
    <records>
        <row>
            <column name="code">0000000180</column>
            <column name="type">3</column>
        </row>
    <records>
</data>
```

I tried with XSD. But have error when I export to XML from Excel 2016:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="header">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="column">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="code"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" fixed="bpchar"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="records">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="row">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="column">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" fixed="code"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My Excel file content:

### Code | Type

001  | V
002  | T
003  | X

Please give me suggestion!

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more about your problem? So far, you 've shown us what you *have* done, but have not said what you *want* to do, or what *problem* you have.

Comment: This is still not clear to me - XSD is a format for *describing* the format of XML files, not for *transforming* or converting them, so how exactly are you using this file? Are you trying to load the data from Postgres to Excel, or the other way (you say "export" for both)? And **always be specific** when mentioning an error - paste the exact wording here.

Comment: This's my Excel file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3IPKV0pleecXNiZmlTZllDY0k/view?usp=sharing)
This's XML after export from Postgres: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3IPKV0pleeWEpmclAtTDI4RUk/view?usp=sharing)
This's XSD file (exported from xsd.exe - a tool of Microsoft SDK): [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3IPKV0pleecWUybXd6N1FvdUk/view?usp=sharing)
Problem is I don't know how to mapping column with this XSD in Excel file. So, I need helping to modify this XSD.

Comment: That hasn't answered my question: what are you trying to *achieve*? Are you trying to export your data in a particular XML format, that matches what you have in Postgres? Why do you think XSD will help you with this? What are you doing with the XSD that is giving you an error? What is the actual error you're getting? Please [edit] your question to include these details.